# Setting access rules on nodes in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, node-neo4j

Iam trying to create a Who know's who type of app and want restrict /render the graph based on  Profile/Who is viewing it  E.g If I am seeing my friends I would see my data and if someone else is seeing it they see their respective data

How to achive this in neo4j

Comment: can you elaborate what is your question?

Comment: Perhaps you can check out these graph modeling examples for some insights: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist/wiki